# Getting a null response when calling a php site function from java in android

Tags: java, php, android, html

I'm trying to call a php function on a site that I have from an android application.

I'm using this to get my response: https://github.com/koush/ion

Here is my php code which is located at : [Link](https://illegible-deflector.000webhostapp.com/Site3/dbtest.php?Tabela=Stroka)
It's used to connect to a database i have on that site. 
The php file just returns all the entries in the database as HTML text shown under the php code (Not sure if this is the proper way to get data from a database).
The Database entries get their own tags so I can handle them later in the app.

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if (isset($_GET['Tabela'])) {
    DobiPodatke($_GET['Tabela']);
} else {
    ECHO '<error>Ni selekcije</error>';
}



function DobiPodatke($Tabela)
{
$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM " . $Tabela;
ZazeniQuery($Tabela, $sqlget);
}


function ZazeniQuery($Ime, $Query){
$sqldata = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbcon'], $Query) or die('<error>error with fetching data</error>');
    ECHO '<' . $Ime . '>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        switch($Ime){
            case 'Sola':
                ECHO '<vnos><Kratka_Oznaka>' . $row['Kratka_Oznaka'] . '</Kratka_Oznaka><Ime>' . $row['Ime'] . '</Ime></vnos>';
                break;
            case 'Stroka':
                ECHO '<vnos><Ime_Stroke>' . $row['Ime_Stroke'] . '</Ime_Stroke></vnos>';
                break;
            case 'Sola_Smer':
                ECHO '<vnos><ID_Sole>' . $row['ID_Sole'] . '</ID_Sole><ID_Stroke>' . $row['ID_Stroke'] . '</ID_Stroke><Stevilo_mest>' . $row['Stevilo_mest'] . '</Stevilo_mest></vnos>';
                break;
        }
    }
    ECHO '</' . $Ime . '>';
}


?>
```

HTML Response:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erMqq.png)

Now in order for this to work I need to supply the php function parameter on which table i need infromation from so I call it like this:

> https://illegible-deflector.000webhostapp.com/Site3/dbtest.php?Tabela=Sola

Tabela beeing the variable I need to pass in otherwise the php does a die()

In the example above I called the php file with "?Tabela=Sola" at the end to get all table entries in the table "Sola".
While this works in the browser, it does not in my application.

Now in my android application I use the Ion library/class to get my response from a website in pure HTML code. It works with a regular website since I can get the whole HTML code from the site.

It however does not work on my php site since i get a null result.

The link variable in the following code is:

> https://illegible-deflector.000webhostapp.com/Site3/dbtest.php?Tabela=Sola

Java code that connects to the website and returns the result:

```
private static void ParseDBFront(String link, Context context){
    Ion.with(context).load(link).setLogging("MyLogs", Log.DEBUG).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
            Log.i("LOG", "LOG: " + result);
        }
    });
}
```

And the response I get from the above code when running is:

> I/LOG: LOG: null

All i need is for the java code to return the HTML code but I have no idea why it won't return the html code.
I'm guessing that i'm parsing my variable in the wrong way.

I appreciate any feedback or solutions to this problem.

Comment: I also get this null on every time when i run and install the apk and request for data from server into the emulator. But when i make request second time it is ok.

Comment: @Md.SojibAhmed could you further explain what exactly you did to get it working on the second request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out myself.
There was no problems with the code as is, the problem was the way i wrote the URL of my php file.

Original link:

> private static final String DBLink = "www.illegible-deflector.000webhostapp.com/Site3/dbtest.php?Tabela=";

And how I fixed it:

> private static final String DBLink = "https://illegible-deflector.000webhostapp.com/Site3/dbtest.php?Tabela=";

That "www." / "https://" difference is all that caused my program to return a null response for some reason.

I don't know why but the problem is gone.